# Setting owner for light scene in Hue-API

Tags: rest, philips-hue

I have a question for all the developers who are working with the Philips Hue-API.
So, I want to create some scenes for two Android-Devices I use with my Philips-Hue lights.

The problem is: if I do create them with the Rest-API I cannot find a way to set the Owner of the scene I create.

So the question is, does anyone has an idea, how to set the owner or at least how to create a scene that every "device" connected to the Hue-Bridge, can see and use?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Scenes are stored on the hub, so they can be queried and presented to the user to be activated on one or more lights. Each scene has an `owner:` attribute, which can be set to whitelist item of the device/app that created the scene.

Scenes are stored in the `scenes:{}` list, so its just a matter of retrieving them and displaying the ones you want to make available to the user of the application. You could show them all, or filter by the `owner:` or any other field in the scene element. If you have a scene editor in your app, you might want to filter and only edit the scenes created by your app's whitelist entry.

You might also want to make use of the scene's new `appdata` element, where you can store arbitrary user-defined information when you create a scene.